# Django: forbid to add the same data for user

Tags: python, django, orm, restriction

I have app where user can add url to favorite in database with ManyToMany relationship. So every user can have a lot of urls and every url can have a lot of users. I have problem with creating restriction to avoid adding the same url for user. I mean I want to create the mechanism where url can be added a lot of time for users, but only one per user.

In my models I have:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Repository(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    repositorys = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user')
```

And in my views:

```
def favorites(request):
    url = request.session.get('url')
    repo = Repository(url=url,user=request.user)
    repo.save()
    repo.repositorys.add(request.user)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    repos = user.users.all()
    return render(request, 'favorites.html',{'url':url,'repos':repos})
```

Favorites function is called on clicked button in my template. When I click the above function is executed and redirect to /favorites. The problem is, when I click again on button and Im logged as the same user, this url is added again to database. Same problem with refreshing ***favorites.html***. Is there any logic way to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

view favorites:

```
def favorites(request):
    url = request.session.get('url')
    try:
        repo = Repository(url=url,user=request.user)
        repo.save()
        repo.repositorys.add(request.user)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        return render_to_response('base.html')
    repos = user.users.all()
    return render(request, 'favorites.html', {'url': url, 'repos': repos})
```

My idea here was to return all urls for user then move adding to try block. When there is a IntegrityError then move to base.html and later will display some messages

Answer (score 1):

Use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in your model to manage uniqueness at the database level

```
class Repository(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')


    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['url', 'user']]
```

then when you want to add a URL for a specific user, handle unique error to prevent a user to add a specific URL twice or more.

```
try:
   # add a Repository
except IntegrityError:
   # raise an error
```

Comment: So, after adding Meta class and makemigrations, during migrate I get IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: app_repository.url, app_repository.user_id

Comment: now you have at least one record in your current database witch are not unique so the migration can't apply

Comment: You must write a migration to remove duplicate records before adding unique constraint to the model.

Comment: Well it looks like it works to some extent - because I can't add again the same url for logged user, but when I just want to display all my favorites (which are at the same endpoint - /favorite - I get an IntegrityError which is served)

Comment: Nice. seems this problem will come from another thing. post the view for /favorite

Comment: Ok. for creating and rendering page, please use two different methods (POST for creating and GET for rendering) or use two endpoint URL.

Comment: I solved it in other way - I created other method which just add data to database and this method is called when form im submitted